# Can I get coordinates of the circle created by `floating.pie` function in `plotrix`?

Tags: r, plot, pie-chart

I was wondering how I can get the **X, and Y values** forming the **"circle" of the pie chart** produced by the "**plotrix**" package in R?

As an example, how can I get the X, and Y values making the **"circle" of the pie chart** produced by **the R code below**:

```
install.packages('plotrix')
library("plotrix")

plot(1:5, type="n", xlab="x", ylab="y",xpd=T)
floating.pie(3, 3, 1, col="white", radius=1)
```

Comment: Zheyuan, thanks very much. Could you possibly be more specific about your response? And there is no way to get x, and y for the circle somehow from the package itself?

Comment: Zheyuan, maybe this sounds like a minor question, but how can I select out **every other x, y** from these x, y's produced? I mean I need to create points on the outer edge of the circle, so I need some **space** between the points on the the circumference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain it on your own using polar coordinates. And `floating.pie` is doing the same.

Let `radius`, `edges`, `xpos` and `ypos` be as same as what you feed `floating.pie`, the circle is determined by the following points:

```
radius <- 1; edges <- 200; xpos <- ypos <- 3

x <- radius * cos(seq(0, 2 * pi, length = edges)) + xpos
y <- radius * sin(seq(0, 2 * pi, length = edges)) + ypos
circle <- cbind(x, y)

plot(1:5, asp = 1)  ## set axis ratio 1:1
polygon(circle)
```

[image]